# Sent email bu URL parameters

Tags: php, web

I have a contact form on my website and i want to send an email to my personal inbox the contact information when user gives. But i want to create a php file and i will set some parameters to the URL of this file (like name,email or message) and i will sent the email with the value of the parameters.

Note: I know how to send the email from my webhost so i don't need help with the email sent.

(sorry for my bad english :-( )

here is my contact form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Contact with me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <h3>George Sepetadelis</h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav_links">
      <li>
        <a class="home"><b>Home</b></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="project"><b>Projects</b></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="aboutme"><b>About me</b></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a  style="color: cadetblue;" class="contact"><b>Contact</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <center>
    <h1 class="contact-title">Contact with me</h1>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-div">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <h2 style="color:darkcyan; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;"><b>Contact form</b></h2>
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" autocomplete="off" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" autocomplete="off" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type here what you want exactly..." required>
            <br><br><br>
            <p style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">Contact reason:</p><br>
            <div class="reason-div" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; ">
                <input type="radio" id="mobile-app" name="reason" value="mobile app">
                <label for="mobile-app">Mobile-app</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="web-app" name="reason" value="web-app">
                <label for="web-app">Web-app</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="desktop-app" name="reason" value="desktop-app">
                <label for="desktop-app">Desktop-app</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="other" name="reason" value="other">
                <label for="other">Other</label>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <button class="submit-contact-form" type="submit"><b>Send contact form </b></button>
            <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
  </center>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you send an email by parameters from your URL you open your website to spam abuse.

Comment: i want to sent it to my personal inbox not to the user

Comment: you know how to do that?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to CSS? If not, please remove that irrelevant tag

Comment: i remove the tags but i want to sent an email with the values of the url parameters but i don't know how to get the url parameters from my php scrip to sent the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you want to post to a php code the input value from the page and do something with it? You can try that, and do your php in the php section at the end :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Contact with me</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h3>George Sepetadelis</h3>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav_links">
  <li>
    <a class="home"><b>Home</b></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="project"><b>Projects</b></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="aboutme"><b>About me</b></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a  style="color: cadetblue;" class="contact"><b>Contact</b></a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<center> 
<h1 class="contact-title">Contact with me</h1>
<br><br>
<div class="form-div">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"> 
        <h2 style="color:darkcyan; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;"><b>Contact 
form</b></h2>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" autocomplete="off" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" autocomplete="off" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type here what you want exactly..." required>
        <br><br><br>
        <p style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">Contact reason:</p><br>
        <div class="reason-div" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; ">
            <input type="radio" id="mobile-app" name="reason" value="mobile app">
            <label for="mobile-app">Mobile-app</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="web-app" name="reason" value="web-app">
            <label for="web-app">Web-app</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="desktop-app" name="reason" value="desktop-app">
            <label for="desktop-app">Desktop-app</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="other" name="reason" value="other">
            <label for="other">Other</label>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <button class="submit-contact-form" type="submit"><b>Send contact form </b> 
</button>
        <br><br>
    </form>
</div>
</center>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<?php

//this is the do something place with PHP

   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   // collect value of input field
      $name = $_POST['name']; //you get it by ID.
      //here I write the name just to do something with it, but you can do whatever you want and send your email then in the php section
   if (empty($name)) {
      echo "Name is empty";
   } else {
      echo $name;
   }  
  }
?>
```

Comment: I think `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` without `htmlspecialchars()` could lead to XSS injection.

Answer (score 1):

To append `GET` parameters to a `POST` form, you can append them to the URL in the `action` attribute:

```
    <form action="?subject=<?= urlencode($subject); ?>#" method="POST">
```

The `#` fragments must be placed after the `?` parameters and the parameters need to be url-encoded.

In the target script you can use those variables from the `$_GET` superglobal:

```
<?php
echo htmlentities($_GET['subject']);
```

Comment: so after do that i will able to do somthing like this? mydomain/file.php?message=blah?name=george and the sent the email?